# Launch iMacros for Chrome from command lines

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, command, imacros

I have seen many posts concerning my issue; but so far nothing works.
So here is a fresh example of my case; based on https://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome#Command_Line_Support

Concerning my configuration, I'm using :

- Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146
- iMacros for Chrome 10.0.1
- macOs High Sierra v10.13.3

I've started a fresh html file using https://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome#Command_Line_Support
So my index.html is :

```
<html>
     <body onload="window.setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'criimlaunch\').click();', 1000);">

        <script>
           var e_m64 = "UFJPTVBUJTIwSEVMTE8hJTBBVVJMJTIwR09UTyUzRGh0dHAlM0ElMkYlMkZpbWFjcm9zLm5ldCUyRiUwQVBST01QVCUyMEJZRSE";
        </script>

        <a id="criimlaunch" href="javascript:(function() {try{if(!/^(?:chrome|https?|file)/.test(location)){alert('iMacros: Open webpage to run a macro.');return;}
           var macro = {};macro.source = decodeURIComponent(atob(e_m64));macro.name = 'MacroBookmarklet';
           var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');evt.initCustomEvent('iMacrosRunMacro', true, true, macro);
           window.dispatchEvent(evt);}catch(e){alert('iMacros Bookmarklet error: '+e.toString());}}) ();">Launch CR iMacros</a>

     </body>
 </html>
```

And I plan to run it from command line with the following command : 
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir "file:///Users/index.html"

I see a new window opening but in command line I have the follwing error :

> Macbook:~ rizze$ /Applications/Google\
>   Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
>   --user-data-dir "file:///Users/rizze/Desktop/RIZZE/fb-spammer/www/iMacros/index.html"
>   Nouvelle fenêtre ouverte dans la session du navigateur
>   [833:85763:0313/085533.690232:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(120)]
>   Failed to launch GPU process.

**What may be the cause of this failed to launch GPU process ?**

Comment: didn't know that tool. Will try it right now. Can I launch it from command line @NicEndo . Very excited to try that tool . Thanks for the share. Kepp you posted

Comment: I managed to do what I wanted with Kantu. Thanks for your help